# == vs equals method for Doubles

Tags: java

I have this class

```
public class Point {
    private Double[] coordinates;
    private int dimension;

    public Point(Double[] coordinates) {
        dimension = coordinates.length;
        this.coordinates = new Double[dimension];

        for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
            this.coordinates[i] = coordinates[i];


    }

    public Double getCoord(int n) {
        if(n < 0 || n > dimension -1 ){
            throw new RuntimeException("error de coordenadas");
        }
        return coordinates[n];
    }
    public int getDim() {
        return dimension;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object p1){
        if( (p1 instanceof Point) ){
            Point p = (Point) p1;
            int n = p.getDim();
            if(getDim() == n)
            {
                for(; n > 0; n--)
                {
                    if( Double.valueOf(this.getCoord(n-1)) != Double.valueOf(p.getCoord(n-1)) ) // <------- BAD LINE!
                    {
                        System.out.println("Checking coord " + (n-1));
                        System.out.println("Coord " + (n-1) + " p = " + Double.valueOf(this.getCoord(n-1)));
                        System.out.println("Coord " + (n-1) + " p2 = " + Double.valueOf(p.getCoord(n-1)));
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this main

```
public class FigureTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Double[] coord1 = {2.0,3.3};
        Double[] coord2 = {2.0,3.3};
        Point p = new Point(coord1);
        Point q = new Point(coord2);
        System.out.println(p.equals(q));
    }
}
```

I can't understand why this `p.equals(q)` returns false! It goes inside the `if( Double.valueOf(...` but then prints that both coordinates are equal. It's the same if I remove the `Double.valueOf`. The only way it worked was when I put `! if(this.getCoord(n-1).equal(p.getCoord(n-1))`, but I don't understand why the others don't work.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `p.equals(q)` and `p == q`? (What does `==` do when used with objects?)

Comment: why don't you use just `Arrays.equals()` in `Point#equals()` method?

Comment: @Radiodef if `.equals` was not overwritten, then it would be the same as `==` : comparing references, right? Else, the equals method of `p`'s class would be called.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Yes, exactly, and it works the same way with `Double`. `==` compares references where `equals` compares value.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Because I didn't know that method, I'm just a begginer. However, I want to know mostly why what I did doesn't work, rather than how to actually implement this.

Comment: because you confuse `Double.valueOf()` with `Double#doubleValue()`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Sorry, I haven't yet learned what the `#` is... However I did understand Radiodef's and Vince Emighs' explanation.

Comment: @Radiodef, Vince Emigh thank you!! I finally understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: `#` means "instance method", i. e. `this.getCoord(n - 1).doubleValue()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleValue%28%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Double.valueOf` returns a `Double` **object**, *not a primitive double*.

You perform a reference check (`!=`). So even if `Double.valueOf(getCoords(n-1))` returned the same numeric value for both calls, *different objects would be wrapping the numbers*, so the != check would be true, causing your equals to return false.

Here's a quick example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(Double.valueOf(5) == Double.valueOf(5));
}
```

Notice how it returns `false`. That's because `==` is a reference check, and  a different object is being returned each time you call `Double.valueOf`. So when you do

```
Double.valueOf(...) != Double.valueOf(...)
```

That check will return true, since the `valueOf` calls didn't return the same object. This is why the check in your code returns `true`, resulting in `equals` returning `false`.

---

**To fix this, you could...**

Change your `!=` check into a `.equals` check, which will compare the numeric values rather than the references.

```
Double.valueOf(...).equals(Double.valueOf(...));
```

This returns `true` if both share the same numeric value.

**Or you could** use `doubleValue()` when you call `getCoord`:

```
getCoord(n-1).doubleValue() != other.getCoord(n-1).doubleValue()
```

This will avoid the excess creation of `Double` objects.

Comment: Or use `this.getCoord(n-1).doubleValue() != p.getCoord(n-1).doubleValue()` to compare primitives

Answer (score -3):

In order to this to work;:

```
p.equals(q)
```

you need to keep the contract between Hashcode and equals and override **properly** both of them: `equals` AND `hashcode` in the class `Point`, and when I write properly I mean specifically this:

Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/982161) if you dont know why or that you dont need it

```
Double.valueOf(this.getCoord(n-1)) != Double.valueOf(p.getCoord(n-1))
```

if the members of the class `Point` are doubles, then you are right when you compare those doubles as criteria to decide if p1.equals(p2)

but according to the [documentation of the class Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare(double,%20double)), the static method `Double.compare(this.getCoord(n-1)),p.getCoord(n-1)` must be use in order to compare 2 doubles content.

hence I recommend to do in the `equals` method some similar to this

```
if( Double.compare(this.getCoord(n-1)),p.getCoord(n-1)!=0) )
```

Comment: why should they implement `hashCode()`??? No hash collections are used here. And they *have implemented* equals(), and the question is "why don't it work".

Comment: @SashaSalauyou - It is just good practice to override hashCode() when you override equals() though it is not required in this case. But in general a class writer must ensure that both the methods are provided if one of them is.

Comment: @user3493289 agree, it is a good practice. But not related to the question in any way. Answer states "you need", as if implementing it would solve the problem.